# Formatting Results of STUFF command that uses For XML Path to concatenate the information into one cell

Tags: sql-server, formatting

I am using a STUFF Command to pull in data from a column and concatenate them together into one cell.

```
STUFF((Select CAST(v.ID as VARCHAR)+ ', '

From Source

Where CriteriaIsMet
For XML Path('')),1,0,'') as MonitorID
```

What I am trying to accomplish is formatting the results at the end. The results from the code above come out like this:

```
 12345, 23456, 34567, 456789,
```

I am looking for the code to have a line break. I want them all to still be in the same cell and not broken up but when placed in Excel I am hoping to have this be the results:

```
12345,
23456,
34567,
45678,
```

I have tried using:

```
 STUFF((Select REPLACE(CAST v.ID as VARCHAR) + ', ' , ', ', +CHAR(13))
```

However the end results don't give me what I am looking for I end up with this:

```
123456&#x0d;234567&#x0D
```

I believe I need to do something at the end of the statement to make this happen, however, I am not sure how to accomplish this because I am using:

```
For XML Path('')),1,0,'')
```

I am hoping that someone may have a simple solution. I would greatly appreciate any assistance. Please note I am trying to keep the data in the same cell. The end result of this data pull goes into a Pivot table in Excel and i'd like for the numbers to display vertically rather than horizontally. When displayed Horizontally the numbers cut off after passing the length of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT STUFF((Select  CAST(v.ID as VARCHAR(30)) +  + ', '+ CHAR(10)
       From Source
       Where CriteriaIsMet
       For XML Path(''),TYPE)
      .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,0,'') as MonitorID
```

Comment: You need to also concatenate `+CHAR(13) + CHAR(13)` (or a string literal with same) to the expression in order to return the result @Xoduszero requested.

Comment: Data still formats horizontally "12345, 23456, 34567, 45678"

Comment: How would you put that in there Dan? Because i've tried the Char 13 and i end up with this weird 123456&#x0d;234567&#x0D

Comment: change your results to show in `text` and you will see a line break , if you try to see the results in a tabular output it will never now in new line.

Comment: you're referring to the pivot table in excel?

Comment: Tried changing to text no line breaks

Comment: M.Ali this does work but now i need to figure out how to make excel display it properly. In excel formula bar it shows in in order vertically like asked. however in the actual Cell it displays it horizontally so now i'm trying to figure out if its possible for excel to format the information that way or not.

Comment: This worked after doing this it was a matter of formatting the pivot table cells to represent the data vertically. Thank you so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `CHAR(13)` and/or `CHAR(10)`, `CHAR(9)` horizontal TAB worked for me. The complete STUFF argument and other possible large text fields should also be CASTED as `varchar(255)`.

Should be something like: `SELECT CAST(STUFF((...) + CHAR(9) as varchar(255)) as MonitorID`