# Delete spaces and special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

This question is linked to :[concatenate a column on one line depends on a id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237624/concatenate-a-column-on-one-line-depends-on-a-id)

I used this query (thanks Mihai) :

```
SELECT id, date,MAX(docline),
Ids=Stuff((SELECT ' ' + doctext  FROM documentation  d WHERE d.id=documentation.id
 FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '' )
 from documentation where date in (02/14/2017)
GROUP BY id,date
```

I received this line :

```
Backup  :                           &#x0D;
D:\Bas.bac                                 &#x0D;
test testtest&#x0D;
tesdttest testtest&#x0D;
```

I would like to have something like :

```
Backup  : D:\Bas.bac test testtest tesdttest testtest
```

So no space and no special characters like ('`&#x0D;`')

Like you can see I have some special characters and too much space... 
I tried to use RTrim() and LTRIM like :

```
SELECT id, date,MAX(docline),
Ids=Stuff(RTRIM(SELECT ' ' + doctext  FROM documentation  d WHERE d.id=documentation.id
 FOR XML PATH ('')))
             , 1, 0, '' )
 from documentation where date in (02/14/2017)
GROUP BY id,date
```

But I don't see any difference and I have the same behavior.

Thanks,

EDIT : I tried too (without success) :

```
Stuff((SELECT ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(doctext))  FROM documentation  d WHERE d.id=documentation.id FOR XML PATH ('')),1,0,'')
```

Comment: I found help here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592810/formatting-results-of-stuff-command-that-uses-for-xml-path-to-concatenate-the-in

Comment: My query seems good now : 'Stuff((SELECT ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(doctext))  FROM documentation  d WHERE d.id=documentation.id FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,0,'') . I still have some spaces... I will see how can I delete them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to remove multiple spaces you could try

```
REPLACE (<string>,'  ', '')
```

But in your case it also remove double space between Backup and :

Comment: Thanks, I accpted your answer because It do the job. I added previous comment because I found another solution. TO delete '&#x0D;' I used the TYPE and for the space, I used RTRIM and LTRIM in the correct place. Thanks!